# Patched Windows boot loader detected (#1)

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

When I try to run Fortnite, this shows up:

[image: Patched Windows boot loader detected error Fortnite]

This happened after I did some changes to the Windows features, but the same thing happens even after I undo everything I changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Try to locate EasyAntiCheat_Setup.exe in the Fortnite directory

(somewhere like:)

*C:\Program Files\Epic Games\Fortnite\Fortnite Game\Binaries\Win64\EasyAntiCheat*

- Click on the executable, accept the UAC (if you have it), and in the EAC window, choose Fortnite and hit repair tool. If this didn't changed a thing, try hit uninstall Easy Anti Cheat, and then reinstall it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: `Fortnite Game` should be `FortniteGame` (no space), at least as of the time of this comment.

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue with EAC (EasyAntiCheat) which Fortnite recently upgraded to, which also seems to detect pirated copies of Windows. Assuming your Windows isn't pirated, some suggestions I found online were:

1. Restart your computer;
2. Configure your antivirus to exclude the EAC executable file;
3. Uninstall your antivirus entirely;
4. Make sure Windows is up to date;
5. run the https://www.boyans.net/dual-boot-repair-windows-10.html boot repair tool (some people claim this might be because of a corrupted boot sector).
6. Contact Fortnite support.

I've also seen claims that clean installing Windows fixes this, but I can understand if you're reluctant to do this.

Comment: My copy of Windows is pirated :P